# Subscript out of range VBA copying to csv

Tags: excel, vba, csv

While writing a piece of code I encountered the "Subscript out of range" message.

The structure of the folder is the following:
D:\Documents main directory
Inside it there are: 
the xls workbook with the code 
a file 1.csv to which I need to copy data
a folder WiP which contains csv files with the data

The code currently looks like this

```
Sub MergeData()
'
' Ìàêðîñ1 Ìàêðîñ

' Provide path to workbooks,
' there is a folder with about 100 csv books from which I should collect data into one

    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WiP\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.csv")

' Open a workbook in which the data should be pasted

    Workbooks.Open ("D:\Documents\1.csv")
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "date"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "hour"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "num"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "p"

' Call the code

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        IntegrateDays wb
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

' Close the workbook with data

    Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Close savechanges:=True


End Sub


Sub IntegrateDays(wb As Workbook)

Dim ws As Worksheet
    With wb

' Open workbooks, copy a range

            Sheets(1).Activate
            Dim rng As Range
                    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
                    rng.Copy

' Paste the range into 1.csv

            Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).Activate
            rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set NextRow = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

The code runs until it has to paste the copied range rng into 1.csv and stops with an error. 
The first guess is that this may be an error related to range.activate. I attempted to test it by doing the operation without loop and only selecting one cell and further by just opening 1.csv prior to even selecting any ranges. The error remains. 
The second suspicion is that there is an issue opening 1.csv. By looking though searches such as "subscript out of range opening csv" I didn't find any heavily discussed issues which would help with this question.

Could you please kindly advise me what caused the error and how to rewrite the code?

Thank you very much in advance.

Evgeniya.

Comment: When you are pasting the data, you are only specifying that it's the 1.csv workbook the first time you try to access the range on the sheet.
Shouldn't Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).Activate be Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).Activate

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `rng.PasteSpecial`. The parent of the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) should be the destination; not the source.

Since you are interested in getting the values over, abandon the PasteSpecial in favor of direct value transfer.

```
Dim rng As Range
with Sheets(1)
    Set rng = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
end with

with Workbooks("D:\Documents\1.csv").Worksheets(1)
    .cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1,0).resize(rng.rows.count, rng.columns.count) = rng.Value
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy from a workbook into others?
Try adjust this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:C").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), _
Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim WBookCopy As Workbook
Dim WBookPst As Workbook
Dim Filepath As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim sheetCopy As Worksheet

Set WBookPst = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Call DeleteCache
'B2 is the location directory of latest Excel file
Filepath = Range("B2").Value
Set WBookCopy = Workbooks.Open(Filepath)

Set sheetPst = WBookPst.Worksheets(2)
Set sheetCopy = WBookCopy.Worksheets(1)

sheetCopy.UsedRange.Copy sheetPst.Range("A:AG")
sheetCopy.UsedRange.Value = sheetCopy.UsedRange.Value

WBookCopy.Close (False)
```